# Как выглядит визуальная привязка(parent) в java?

Tags: java

Как выглядит визуальная привязка(parent) в java? Например в питоне это выглядит так:

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.class2 = Class2(self)

    def Hello(self):
        print('Hello')


class Class2():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.Hello()

a = Class1()
```

Comment: что такое визуальная привязка?

Comment: Без использования наследования, можно использовать родительские компоненты. В коде написанном на питоне, Class2 использует при своей инициализации функцию Class1 и при этом он не наследуется от Class1.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит также:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 a = new Class1();
    }
}

class Class1 {
    Class2 class2;

    public Class1() {
        class2 = new Class2(this);
    }

    public void Hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

class Class2 {
    Class1 parent;

    public Class2(Class1 parent) {
        super();
        this.parent = parent;
        this.parent.Hello();
    }
}
```